# Get parent term_id from get_term_children

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to make a list of all children (subcategories) of a taxonomy category.

Found this function (get_term_children) on developer
[developer wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children//)
that does what I want, but I have to manually input the parents id.

```php
<?php
$term_id = 10;
$taxonomy_name = 'products';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

How can I dynamically get the parent id of the current taxonomy page?

Cheers,
Dennis

Searched stackoverlow, and tried a few methodes, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/)

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 
$parent = $queried_object->parent;
```

Comment: Thank you @Moishy, I ended up using the wp_get_post_terms to get the parent id of current active page.


$postterms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,$taxonomy,array('parent'=>0));
$parentId = $postterms[0]->term_id;

Using get_queried_object would not get me the top taxonomy category on a subcategory page.

Cheers.